# Грамотно ли проставлены тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Издалека они увидели две горки: одну белую, другую – черную. Они решили, что белая будет брату, а черная сестре. Белая горка оказалась солью, а черная – финиками.

Правильно ли стоят тире? По-моему, их не хватает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Издалека они увидели две горки: одну (1) белую, другую (2) черную. Они решили, что белая будет брату, а черная (3) сестре. Белая горка оказалась солью, а черная (4) финиками.**

(1) и (2). Тире ставится в однотипно построенных частях сложного предложения при пропуске какого-либо члена (иногда и без пропуска): Они смотрели друг на друга: Райский — с холодным любопытством, она — с дерзким торжеством (Гонч.);  ([§ 6. Тире в неполном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93,3#pp93))

(3) и (4). Тире ставится в неполном предложении, составляющем часть сложного предложения, когда пропущенный член (обычно сказуемое) восстанавливается из предыдущей части фразы и в месте пропуска делается пауза:Ермолай стрелял, как всегда, победоносно; я — довольно плохо (Т.) ([§ 6. Тире в неполном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93,3#pp93))

Однако можно эти тире и не ставить:

> Примечание. Тире может отсутствовать при меньшей интонационной расчлененности предложения: Они заговорили обе сразу: одна про коров, другая про овец, но слова не доходили до сознания Куземкина (Бел.); Со второго слова она мне: «А есть ли, батюшка, деревеньки?» (Дост.); Я к вам, посидеть; то же в предложениях, характеризующих субъект по местонахождению: Секретарь у директора; Он на заседании. ([Тире в неполном предложении](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=107))

Я бы предпочел вариант без тире:

**Издалека они увидели две горки: одну белую, другую черную. Они решили, что белая будет брату, а черная сестре. Белая горка оказалась солью, а черная финиками.**

Answer (score 4):

Еще один вариант постановки знаков препинания:

**Издалека они увидели две горки: одну бЕлую, другую  чЁрную. Они решили, что белая будет брАту, а чёрная  сестрЕ. БЕлая горка //оказалась сОлью, а чЁрная – фИниками.**

Пояснение

Постановка тире соответствует параллельной интонации, которая. как мне кажется, больше подходит для последнего предложения. Тире здесь ставится на месте пропуска двух слов.